# Datatrigger in WPF Style: Change content doesn't work

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have some style coding for a custom maximize `Button` and i'm getting some issues.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
       <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                   <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="0">
                       <ContentPresenter  Margin="10,7,10,7" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                   </Border>
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="#01000000"/>
       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
       <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
       <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="#50FFFFFF"/>
           </Trigger>
           <!--This trigger fails-->
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=acrylic:AcrylicWindow}}" Value="Maximized">
               <Setter Property="Content">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <Grid>
                           <Path Height="10" Width="10" Data="M2,0 L8,0 L8,6 M0,3 L6,3 M0,2 L6,2 L6,8 L0,8 Z"
                               Stroke="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                               StrokeThickness="1"
                               SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                       </Grid>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
           </DataTrigger>
           <!--It Works Correctly-->
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=acrylic:AcrylicWindow}}" Value="Normal">
               <Setter Property="Content">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <Grid>
                           <Path Width="10" Height="10" Data="F1M0,0L0,9 9,9 9,0 0,0 0,3 8,3 8,8 1,8 1,3z"
                             Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                             SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                       </Grid>
                   </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
          </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

When the `Window` is maximized the `Button` content disappears, it doesn't show the path, it's empty (but clickable and the fade in InMouseOver works). When the `Window` is in normal state the button content is correct.
I was trying to change the path data but i didn't see any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define the content as a resource:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Grid x:Key="max">
            <Path Height="10" Width="10" Data="M2,0 L8,0 L8,6 M0,3 L6,3 M0,2 L6,2 L6,8 L0,8 Z"
                               Stroke="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                               StrokeThickness="1"
                               SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Key="normal">
            <Path Width="10" Height="10" Data="F1M0,0L0,9 9,9 9,0 0,0 0,3 8,3 8,8 1,8 1,3z"
                             Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                             SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
        </Grid>

    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="0">
                    <ContentPresenter  Margin="10,7,10,7" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#01000000"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#50FFFFFF"/>
        </Trigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Value="Maximized">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource max}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Value="Normal">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource normal}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Wow, works like a charm. Thanks. Do you know why of this behavior? I'm quite new in WPF

Comment: It's because of the Foreground binding. If you set the Stroke of the Path to a fixed value your example will probably work.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is this line:

```
Stroke="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
```

The reason for that is that this binding cannot be resolved when the setter is being instantiated, because the `Path` does not yet exist.

When you use

```
Stroke="#FFFFFFFF"
```

instead, it will work.

Define the color in a resource and use something like

```
Stroke="{StaticResource ButtonForegroundColor}"
```

for better maintainability of your XAML code.